# How to add a user input field to a URL

Tags: php, forms, user-input

I have a PHP generated list of product links that, when clicked, adds a product to a shopping cart.  At present, there's a quantity of '1' hard-coded in the links, e.g.

`<a href="/shop/checkout?1[sku]=$sku&1[qty]=1"> Add To Cart </a>`

I'd like to add a quantity field to each item in the list, so a customer can add the quantity they want to the cart.

This list doesn't use a form, so how could I introduce a user input qty field and use it in each link?  My searches have turned up nothing, so I take it that it can't be done the way I have it set up now.  No matter how I change this list, I need to pass an array to the /shop/checkout PHP script.

I'm probably looking at this the wrong way, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

It must have something to do with the fact that my product list is in a table.  When I change your example to use a table instead of divs, it breaks.  Here's a sample:

```
<table class="products_list">
<tr class="product_list--item">
    <td> 12486XC4 </td>
    <td> Amount: <span class="item_display--1[qty]">1</span> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> <input class="item_qty" id="itm_qty" type="number" min="1" max="100" value="1" size="5" /> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> <a href="https://www.example.com/checkout/?1[sku]=12486XC4&1[qty]=1">Add to cart</a> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="product_list--item">
    <td> 13486XC5 </td>
    <td> Amount: <span class="item_display--1[qty]">1</span> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> <input class="item_qty" id="itm_qty" type="number" min="1" max="100" value="1" size="5" /> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> <a href="https://www.example.com/checkout/?1[sku]=13486XC5&1[qty]=1">Add to cart</a> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="product_list--item">
    <td> 14486XC6 </td>
    <td> Amount: <span class="item_display--1[qty]">1</span> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> <input class="item_qty" id="itm_qty" type="number" min="1" max="100" value="1" size="5" /> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> <a href="https://www.example.com/checkout/?1[sku]=14486XC6&1[qty]=1">Add to cart</a> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Also, `1[sku]` and `1[qty]` are invariable in the links.  They are used in the destination PHP script for each product on this page.  The *only* thing that changes from product to product is the value of the sku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **javascript** for this instead of one big form and complex php code. Simply put each link in the wrapper with `<input type="number"/>` that will allow to add quantity to your product. Then you can change `URI` for checkout. Working example with comments of how to do this i have add below.

Hope that this will help!

**Update**

Because you are not showing your code its hard to understand what is not working on your side. So show us what you did and lets find out the issues instead of pin pointing the problem ;)

I don't see any issues with rendering your template using **php** and putting values of proper variables as a values of html attributes.
You can add **name** attribute which can be equal to your qty array name for proper sku. Example

`<input name="1[qty]" class="item_qty" type=number min="1" max="100" value="1" />`.

In **php** it will look like this (**and again this is just an example of how you can achieve your result**)

`<input name="<?="1[qty]={$qty}";?>" class="item_qty" type=number min="<?=$qty;?>" max="100" value="1" />`

`<?=?>` is an echo tag. You can replace with `<?php ?>`

Later you can simply grab the value of the attribute using **JS** and update each corresponding checkout link. Moreover your case didn't work because in RegExp symbols like `[` and `]` should be escaped -> `\[` and `\]`.

```js
function addSlashes(string, vowels) {
  let length = vowels.length;
  let finalString = "";
  let startOffset = 0;
  let endOffset = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if ((endOffset = string.indexOf(vowels[i])) !== -1) {
      finalString += string.substring(startOffset, endOffset) + "\\";
      if (endOffset === string.length - 1) {
        finalString += string[string.length - 1];
      }
      startOffset = endOffset;
    }
  }

  return finalString;
}

function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  let escapedKey = addSlashes(key, ["[", "]"]);
  let re = new RegExp("([?&])" + escapedKey + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  let separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  } else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}

function displayQuantityForProduct(element, text = "") {
  element.textContent = text;
}

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".product_list--item .item_qty");
const length = inputs.length;

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener("input", function() {
    // also add check whenever input value is not an empty string and its an integer which is bigger or equal to 1
    if (this.value && parseInt(this.value) >= 1) {
      // selfName 
      let selfName = "1[qty]";
      let children = this.closest(".product_list--item").children;
      // children will consist of td elements from each tr with class product_list--item in your table
      // [0] first element of the array is sku (1) <td> 12486XC4 </td>
      // [1] second element of the array is amount with span (2)
      // [2] is input with qty (3)
      // [3] is Add to cart link (4) and so on...
      let displayQty = children[1].firstElementChild;
      let addToCartLink = children[3].firstElementChild;
      let newUri = updateQueryStringParameter(
        addToCartLink.getAttribute("href"),
        selfName,
        this.value
      );
      displayQuantityForProduct(displayQty, this.value);
      addToCartLink.setAttribute("href", newUri);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<table class="products_list">
  <tr class="product_list--item">
    <td> 12486XC4 </td>
    <td> Amount: <span class="item_display--1[qty]">1</span> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> <input class="item_qty" id="itm_qty" type="number" min="1" max="100" value="1" size="5" /> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> <a href="https://www.example.com/checkout/?1[sku]=12486XC4&1[qty]=1">Add to cart</a> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product_list--item">
    <td> 13486XC5 </td>
    <td> Amount: <span class="item_display--1[qty]">1</span> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> <input class="item_qty" id="itm_qty" type="number" min="1" max="100" value="1" size="5" /> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> <a href="https://www.example.com/checkout/?1[sku]=13486XC5&1[qty]=1">Add to cart</a> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product_list--item">
    <td> 14486XC6 </td>
    <td> Amount: <span class="item_display--1[qty]">1</span> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> <input class="item_qty" id="itm_qty" type="number" min="1" max="100" value="1" size="5" /> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> <a href="https://www.example.com/checkout/?1[sku]=14486XC6&1[qty]=1">Add to cart</a> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, Sergey, but I can't get it to work.  I see it works in your snippet, though.  One difference I noted is that you used different variables than I did - sku & qty instead of 1[sku] & 1[qty].  So I changed this part of the script:  
  
`let newUri = update_query_string_parameter(  
 addToCartLink.getAttribute("href"),  
 "1[qty]",  
 this.value  
);`  
  
but that didn't help.  
  
In case this wasn't clear before, the link is generated by my PHP script, so that could be why qty is not updating.

Comment: It's generating output like this: `https://www.example.com/checkout/?1[sku]=2&1[qty]=1&1[qty]=2&1[qty]=3&1[qty]=4&1[qty]=5` depending on how many times the increment button is clicked.

Comment: Added some code above as just changing your example to use a table breaks it.

Comment: @FrankJance snippet is updated. I have add working example for table case.) And thank you for cooperation!

Comment: Thank you, Sergey!  This is amazing.  I finally got it to work on my setup.  It was a lot more complex than my example, but your clear explanations allowed me to understand what was going on and to be able to adapt it to my scenario.  Thanks again.  You went above and beyond.  : )

Comment: If I could ask you one last question.  This code needs to be on multiple pages, so how would I wrap that for() loop so I can place the code in an external file and call it from there? When I save it as-is in another file, and include that file, the qty doesn't get updated.

Comment: Hey, Sergey - never mind.  I figured it out.  I just wrapped your code in an anonymous function, then called the external file at the bottom of the page, and it works!  I'm starting to warm to JavaScript! ; )  Thanks again!  Your post was immensely helpful.